# Does the amount of Crimson Hearts destroyed reset when quitting the game?

Tags: terraria

If I destroy a Crimson Heart, go out of the game entirely, and go back in, will my destroyed Crimson Heart count reset to 0 or will it stay at 1 so I only have to break 2 more to summon the Brain of Cthulhu?

Answer (score 5):

The amount of destroyed Shadow Orbs or Crimson Hearts is tied to the world, and will be saved when you quit a single-player world.